# Trouble adding a Swift file to an app's Resource Bundle

Tags: ios, swift, email, attachment

For my app I need to be able to send emails with various type of attachments - directly from the app. I found some solutions and tested them.

If I tried to send a .zip or .txt files from my app, it worked fine. But I could not send a file of type ".swift". Does somebody know how it could work?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    var EmailTxt = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setEmailTxt()
        sendEmail()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }

    func sendEmail() {
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mail.setToRecipients(["sgamesro@gmail.com"])
            mail.setMessageBody(EmailTxt, isHTML: true)
            mail.setSubject("test email")

            if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "swift") {
                print("# File path loaded.")

                if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
                    print("File data loaded.")
                    mail.addAttachmentData(fileData as Data, mimeType: "swift", fileName: "test.swift")

                }
            }

            present(mail, animated: true)
        } else {
            // show failure alert
            print("# func sendEmail() Mistake")
        }
    }

    func setEmailTxt() {
        EmailTxt = "<p>test line 01</p> <p>test line 02</p>" //<p>This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
    }

    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error message, or does the file simply not show up as attached?

Comment: No, I did not get any errors. There is a body of an email without any attachment at all.

Comment: What prints out when you run this?

Comment: Try with mime type `text/plain`

Comment: Do you actually have `test.swift` in your app's resource bundle?

Comment: Yes, rmaddy, I have such a file. :)

Comment: To DoesData: I got no prints by .swift. If I sent a txt file, I get: # File path loaded. and # File data loaded.

Comment: To Scriptable: Tried, the same result.

Comment: I'm curious, why would you want to send a .swift file in the first place?

Comment: @Roman How far does your code get when you run it? If the `if let filePath` isn't entered, then you do not actually have a `test.swift` in your app bundle.

Comment: To Laffen: It belongs to the app idea: a user will get a swift file, which could be used for another apps.

Comment: @rmaddy: As far as I can see, all functions are going up to the end. I get no mistakes. The emal body is created. But without any attachment.

Comment: I ran this code with a txt file and a swift file. The swift file is not loaded. The path is nil. You can verify this because you stated above **If I sent a txt file, I get: # File path loaded. and # File data loaded.** Perhaps you can't load swift files?

Comment: @DoesData: I have three files in my app: test.zip., test.txt and test.swift. The first two can be loaded and the last one not. That is exactly my problem.

Comment: swift files would be compiled by xcode and would not be copied as a resource. so Swift files wouldn't normally be accessible via a bundle. Goto your project settings, select your main target > build settings > copy bundle resources and make sure that test.swift is listed there. If it is not then it wont be available in the bundle. try and add it and then try again

Comment: @Scriptable: Thanks for this idea, but where exactly should I insert test.swift? What should I look for in build settings?

Comment: Build phases, and then find copy bundle resources in the list. expand that and add test.swift. I think this will solve your issue

Comment: I tried adding it to bundle resources and it still didn't load the file.

Comment: @Scriptable: Have added test.swift copy bundle ressources. The same result. It is a pity: Your idea seemed to be good.

Comment: @Scriptable I was just testing this. Even if you add the `swift` file to "Copy Resources", Xcode ends up putting the compiled swift file (which is two files, neither with the .swift extension. It's strange because in my case, the swift file is not listed under "Compile Sources" but Xcode compiles it any way.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, I am finding the same thing. Roman. do you have to store the file as a swift file? store it as text and when you come to share you can change the name that the user gets (fairly sure that is true?)

Comment: @Scriptable: Yes, it could be a way. I will test it, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues here. Xcode doesn't like putting .swift files in the resource bundle.

The first obvious fix is to go to the "Copy Bundle Resources" section under "Build Phases" for your target and add the .swift file.

This sort of works. But it doesn't copy the raw .swift file, it copies two related files associated with the compiled version of the .swift file.

And there doesn't seem to be a way to prevent Xcode from compiling the Swift file even if it isn't listed under the "Compile Sources" section of "Build Phases".

Here's what I would do:

Rename the .swift file you want in your app bundle to .swiftx for some other similar field extension. Make sure the file is in the list under "Copy Bundle Resources".

Then update your code to something like:

```
if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "swiftx") {
    print("# File path loaded.")

    if let fileData = Data(contentsOf: fileURL) {
        print("File data loaded.")
        mail.addAttachmentData(fileData, mimeType: "text/plain", fileName: "test.swift")
    }
}
```